# C++ project: Where to define global variable with function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, global-variables, project

I'm writing a C++ project where, at some point, I need to generate a list of random numbers, which I call "Zobrist" numbers. I tried to do something like this:

File "zobrist.h":

```
#ifndef ZOBRIST_H
#define ZOBRIST_H

namespace Zobrist
{
int ZOBRIST_NUMBERS[64];
bool ZOBRIST_NUMBERS_GENERATED;
void GENERATE_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS();
}

#endif // ZOBRIST_H
```

File "zobrist.cpp":

```
#include "zobrist.h"

bool Zobrist::ZOBRIST_NUMBERS_GENERATED = false;

void Zobrist::GENERATE_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS()
{
    for (uint i=0; i!=64; ++i) 
    {
        ZOBRIST_NUMBERS[i] = // Something
    }
    ZOBRIST_NUMBERS_GENERATED = true;
};
```

And then in several other files of my project, I want to include "zobrist.h" and write things like:

```
if (!Zobrist::ZOBRIST_NUMBERS_GENERATED) {Zobrist::GENERATE_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS();}
int x = Zobrist::ZOBRIST_NUMBERS[0] // etc.
```

However this does not compile and I don't understand why. I get errors like `multiple definition of Zobrist::ZOBRIST_NUMBERS`.  (I tried throwing some "extern" key words in "zobrist.h" but it did not solve the errors.)

Where am I going wrong and what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I see that your question is answered, but would still like to comment on your design: you delegate responsibility of initializing those `Zobrist` numbers to the consumers of your class. They should not know or care about `ZOBRIST_NUMBERS_GENERATED` and `GENERATE_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS()`. The traditional approach to this is a singleton or a global class instance that provides you those numbers, with a simple interface like `Zobrist::GetNext()` or `Zobrist::Get(int index)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header file contains **definitions** of several variables, and that header is included in multiple source file, so multiple source files have their own copy of those variables.  When you then attempt to link the compiled object files, it results in a multiple definition error.

You need to *declare* the variables in the header using the `extern` keyword, then define them in exactly one source files, probably zobrist.cpp.  So your header would contain this:

```
namespace Zobrist
{
extern int ZOBRIST_NUMBERS[64];
extern bool ZOBRIST_NUMBERS_GENERATED;
void GENERATE_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS();
}
```

And zobrist.cpp would contain this:

```
bool Zobrist::ZOBRIST_NUMBERS_GENERATED = false;
int Zobrist::ZOBRIST_NUMBERS[64];
```

Comment: I would opt to just hide the `int[]` and `bool` altogether. Rename `GENERATE_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS()` to `GET_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS()`, have it return an `int*` to a private array, and then have it handle the generation of that array the first time it is called, eg: `int* GET_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS() { static int numbers[64] = {}; static bool generated = false; if (!generated) { ... generated = true; } return numbers; }` ... `int *numbers = Zobrist::GET_ZOBRIST_NUMBERS(); int x = numbers[0]; // etc...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks! I will follow your suggestion. That's very helpful.